# Colab FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'labelfile_path'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have 2 folders that I have mounted in my data folder on G-drive. So the structure is

Data -> Train and Test folders --> Train has Trainlabel and Trainimage. Test has 500 Testlabel in CSV format and Testimage has 500 images in jpg format. However, I am not able to open all the labels CSV. The last line is giving an error. Can anyone please help? I have wasted 2 days to get around this issue:

Colab Code is:

```
FolderA=os.chdir ('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/Train/1_Trainlabel/')
FolderB=os.chdir ('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/Train/1_Trainimage/')

a=os.listdir(FolderA)

for k in range(len(a)):

Label_folder='/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/Train/1_Trainlabel' + '/' + a[k]
img_folder='/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/Train/1_Trainimage' + '/' + a[k]
    
folders=!ls(Label_folder)

for i in range(len(folders)):
        
foldername=folders[i]

Label_folder1 = os.path.join(Label_folder,foldername)

img_folder1 = os.path.join(img_folder,foldername)

imgfiles = !ls (img_folder1)

labelfiles=!ls (Label_folder1)

for j in range(len(labelfiles)):

file_name=labelfiles[j]      

labelfile_path=os.path.join(Label_folder1,pspifiles[j])

imgfile_path=os.path.join(img_folder1,imgfiles[j])

**labelfile=open("labelfile_path", "r")**
```

The above line is giving an issue.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'labelfile_path' in the last line of the attached code.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: try `labelfile=open(labelfile_path, "r")`